# OrderBy with Linq.Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a problem to create a sort expression.

I have an expression of type `Expression<Func<Products, bool>>` that already contains a query expression.
I am wanting to do the query ordering, but did not succeed.

Below, in CreateSortExpression method has a error:

```
private Expression<Func<Products, bool>> CreateOrderQuery(Expression<Func<Products, bool>> condition, descriptorOrder item)
{        
    condition= condition.AndAlso(CreateSortExpression(item.PropertyName));        

    return condition;
}

private Expression<Func<Products, bool>> CreateSortExpression(string p)
{
    Expression<Func<Products, bool>> condition = products => 
          p.OrderBy(products.Options.price);

    return condition;
}
```

Error message **'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**

Has anyone gone through this could help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to call `OrderBy` on your `string p`?

Comment: Yes, does not make much sense to say that the property will sort based on the lambda context. But I could not call OrderBy otherwise..

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to build an expression to pass to `OrderBy()`.
You don't want to call `OrderBy()` in that expression; you would want something like `p => p.Something`

Comment: Hi @SLaks. Yes, I am trying to build an expression to pass to OrderBy().